# Which Stack Exchange site to go to to ask questions about if the filling of an everyday object is safe for contact or potentially hazardous?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I accidentally opened a Jiffy bag the wrong way and contacted the filling and breathed it in as it got into the air.

I wanted to post a question regarding whether this whole thing was safe but not sure which site to go to. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Its probably worth looking up what filling those things use and the toxicity of that - a quick google search suggests its paper filling and probably is non toxic.

Comment: If you've been in contact with a hazardous/toxic substance, seek medical attention. When in doubt, do too. Don't go asking on SE and risk dying while waiting for someone to recommend the right site and then waiting for an answer there.

Answer (score 5):

The best option seems to be [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/search?q=toxicity).
Searching for `toxicity` yields the following results, for example, similar to your question:

- [Elderberry seeds toxicity](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/15689/elderberry-seeds-toxicity)
- [Should synthetic cloth materials be avoided?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/9515/should-synthetic-cloth-materials-be-avoided)

It might be best to ask this on [their meta site](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/) first, though, because "*often asked questions that are off-topic include: medical advice for yourself or others*". Framing your question to ask after the potential toxicity of the material likely circumvents this problem.

---

It might also suit [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/).

Searching again for `toxicity`, the following results have similarities with your question:

- [Toxic christmas trees?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/toxic-christmas-trees)
- [What harmful products are used in shampoo, conditioner and body wash that I should avoid?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4671/what-harmful-products-are-used-in-shampoo-conditioner-and-body-wash-that-i-shou/)
- [Can I recycle plastics at home by melting and molding?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/225/can-i-recycle-plastics-at-home-by-melting-and-molding/)

On this site you might want to emphasize the potential negative impact of the materials involved on all living things, though.